# Can't find where the problem is with this switch statement it always show a red underline in case syntax in my VS code editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mern

//I Want to add some of the Icons in my Project to make a tik-tak-toe application so wrote this code, simply made an Icon function, and switch statement to whether It will circle, cross or pen ```

```
const Icon = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div>
    
      switch (name){ 
      case 'crcle': return
      return<FaRegCircle className="Icons" />
      case 'cross':
      return<FaTimes className="Icons" />
      default: 
      return<FaPen className="Icons" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

export default Icon;

[enter image description here][1]
[I'm new in ReactJs, I want to build a tik-take-toe game using react but whenever I placed logic in Icon.js file of the component folder, I got an error which shows a red underline of my switch case that "expression expected." in case statement in switch, Surprised to see even I write the same exact code which tutor show in the tutorial though I got error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ0mN.png) ```

Comment: It looks in your first case statement, you have write `return` extra, Just remove it! make it like this `case 'crcle':`

Comment: Agreed, extra `return` in the first case. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: @SuneelKumar After fixing the extra return and circle keyword it still shows the same error

Answer (score 1):

The switch statement cannot be inlined here.
You need to create a function and put the switch statement inside.

And any JavaScript code inside JSX should be wrapped with `{}`.

```js
const Icon = ({ name }) => {
  const renderIcon = () => {
    switch (name) { 
      case 'crcle':
        return <FaRegCircle className="Icons" />
      case 'cross':
        return <FaTimes className="Icons" />
      default: 
        return <FaPen className="Icons" />
     }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {renderIcon()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Icon;
```

Comment: I'm glad it is.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if you find it helpful